# Как вывести вызванную функцию? Как возвращать vector из функции?

Tags: c++

Теперь вызванную функцию не получается вывести. Пожалуйста, помогите как сможете! Вот часть моего кода:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int>merge_sort(vector<int>a){
    if(a.size()<=1){
        return a;
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<int>a{3,5,6,1,2,7,4};
    cout<<merge_sort(a); //теперь здесь не получается вывести
}
```

Comment: Возвращать вектор - именно так, как у вас. Только функция у вас описана, как возвращающая не вектор, а `int`. Так что как понять, что вы хотите - не знаю...

Comment: @Harry, return vector<int>a; если Вы это имеете в виду, то это тоже не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на определение функции `merge_sort`, точнее на ее тип возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов то, что возвращать vector я понял, но как именно делать-нет

Comment: Неверно. Как ВОЗВОРАЩАТЬ Вы поняли, и возвращаете правильно. Вы не поняли как ОБЪЯВИТЬ - что Вы возвращаете. Обратите внимание на заголовок функции: `int merge_sort(vector<int>a)`. Какой тип возвращаемого значения Вы указали, и какой Вам нужен?

Comment: @LLawliet что ж вы такой непонятливый? int merge_sort(std::vector<int>) замените на std::vector<int> merge_sort(std::vector<int>) - у вас же несоответствие типов

Comment: `std::cout` не может просто так на экран вывести вектор. Надо либо явно написать функцию а-ля `void print(const vector<int>&)`, в которой в цикле выводить содержимое вектора, либо перегрузить `operator<<`, например, так https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-cpp-print-contents-vector-map-pair/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во 2-й ветви условия надо тоже что то возвращать

```
vector<int>merge_sort(vector<int>a)
{
    if(a.size()<=1)
        return a;
   return vector<int>();
}

....
for (const auto& val : merge_sort(a))
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
```